# Ruby on Rails - verify some undefined in model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users registration procedure on my app. But my users have to register with promo code.
So I have model Promocodes for that:

```
  t.references :user #this is who have create that promo, e.g. Admin
  t.string :name #a "name" for promo, e.g. "some_promo"
  t.integer :allowreg #how much registrations  can be done using that promo key
```

So now, when registering, I have to check promo. But how it can be done?! Here is my view for signup form:

```
        <% form_for @user do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_messages %>
            <fieldset>
                <ol>
                  <li>
                    <%= f.label "Promo key" %>

                   ??????????????????????????????????
                                        There have to be a field for promo key
                                       ???????????????????????????????????


                  </li>
                    <li>
                        <%= f.label :login, 'Login' %>
                        <%= f.text_field :login %>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <%= f.label :email %>
                        <%= f.text_field :email %>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <%= f.label :password, "Pass" %>
                        <%= f.password_field :password %>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Pass again' %>
                        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="buttons">
                <%= submit_tag 'Signup!' %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I wish I could help, but I really don't understand the question.  What's missing?

Comment: On my user registration form i want to have a field for promo code. So when user signing up, he/she have to enter that promo code. I have a model for Promocodes with (name and number of allowed registration for that code). The problem is: HOW to check if provided promo code exists when registering.

Comment: ... if provided promo code exists AND VALID (so allowreg have to be >0). The problem is I have no connection between User and Promocode models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001605) - I think that should help.

Comment: May be so, I can't really understand for now how. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. here is the solution:

On User model using combination of

```
  attr_accessor :promocode
```

and

```
  attr_accessible: promocode
```

let you to use :promocode as param. And you will get access to @user.promocode for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to muck up your user model with the promocode attribute, I think you can use the [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001731) (and corresponding [`label_tag`]) from within your `form_for`. Something like:

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <%= label_tag "promo_key" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "promo_key" %>

  <%= f.label :login, 'Login' %>
  <%= f.text_field :login %>

  <%# ...other fields go here... %>

  <%= f.submit 'Signup!' %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in your controller's create action, you can simply access the entered promo code by checking `params[:promo_code]`.

```
def create  
  @user = User.new(params[:user]) #build up the user object 
  promo_code = PromoCodes.find_by_name(params[:promo_code]) #find the promo code that user entered

  if promo_code.allow_reg == 0 #make sure that the code has uses left
    flash[:notice] = "That promo code has expired. Whoops!"
    render :action => 'new'
  else

    if @user.save 
      #i assume you want to decrement the allow_reg on a successful registration?
      promo_code.update_attribute :allow_reg, promo_code.allow_reg - 1

      flash[:notice] = "User account created! Please log in with your new account"  
      redirect_to login_url  
    else  
      render :action => 'new'  #user couldn't be saved. validation error?
    end 

  end 
end
```

Would that work too?  (I'd probably consider moving the promocode checking out of the create action and into a before filter, to keep things cleaner.)

-John

Answer (score 0):

Here your new code

ADD in USER MODEL
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :promocode

??????????????????????????????????
                                        Here your new code
                                       ???????????????????????????????????

                                    
                                      
                                       '12345' %>

```
                              </li>
                                    <li>
                                            <%= f.label :login, 'Login' %>
                                            <%= f.text_field :login %>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                            <%= f.label :email %>
                                            <%= f.text_field :email %>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                            <%= f.label :password, "Pass" %>
                                            <%= f.password_field :password %>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Pass again' %>
                                            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
                                    </li>
                            </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="buttons">
                            <%= submit_tag 'Signup!' %>
                    </div>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :promocode
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :promocode
end
```

Then in your view you can use:

```
<% f.fields_for :promocode do |promocode_form| %>
  <% promocode_form.text_field :code_key %>
<% end %>
```

In your promo code model you can write whatever validations you want (perhaps via a cusomt use def validate method), when your user controller action 'create' tries to save the user object it will also save/validate the promocode, find out more about it here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html